# Symfony2 bundle as a plugin

Tags: php, symfony, architecture

Consider situation where I have some default bundle that hypothetically create some empty page with menu on left and some content (if there is any). Then I create a new bundle and I normally turn it on in AppKernel. Now should magic start: bundle by his own (no need to add any options in default bundle etc.) hooks up and creates his menu entry (and if chosen, renders his content). How should I do this, is there any proper way to do this? What if I want to have multiple "hooks", for example, adding also new form in user profile edit, or adding new tab on some other place?

I'm thinking about looking for some "initialize bundle event" that I could listen to and pass data thru it. But maybe there is better solution. I would love to see your ideas :)

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the `initializeBundles` method of the `Kernel`, it doesn't look easy or intended to dynamically add bundles during the bootup process.

However, the AppKernel.php file is on the forefront, it is an override of `Kernel` and can be customized to supply a dynamic set of bundles to the implemented `registerBundles` method.

You will need to make sure the imported content is properly added to the autoloader, but avoid modifying the distribution source at runtime, try to make it as imported as possible.

I don't want to go into great detail on the technicalities as I have not done this myself and it will require a lot of experimentation.  I do know that Drupal 8 uses Symfony2 and has its own plugin system, but I don't think it takes bundles as plugins.

If you manage to pull this off I suspect it will allow 100% integration between the application and the plugins, but just be aware that it also allows 100% overriding access to said plugins.